# Add iPhone 5 xib for iOS 4 App

Tags: iphone, xcode, xib

I developed an app for iPad and iPhone using `MainWindow.xib` and `MainWindow_pad.xib`.
The Main Interface for iPhone/iPod is `MainWindow` and for iPad `MainWindow_pad.xib`

Now we want support for the iPhone 5.
The App has to be compatible to iOS 4, so I cannot use AutoSizing.
Therefore I created `MainWindow_5.xib` for iPhone 5.

Now is the questions where I can load the `MainWindow_5.xib`??

In `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` or before?

I have been searching the internet up and down and didn't find a working solution.
I cannot be the only one facing this problem?

I hope to get some help to solve this :)

Comment: SOLVED

I put everything in one xib and select the viewcontroller in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions".

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using "old" autoresizingMasks?

i.e. UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight

You should be able to set the mask up in the way to easily work on iPhone 5/4 and support backward compatibility.

Comment: I already have the xibs finished and they fit the designer's requirements perfect.
So I need to use the other xib.

Comment: Understandable.   Though, from personal experience, if apple happens to release another device with slightly different screen dimensions, you would have to create another xib.   It might take a bit more time now, but you will find that relative layouts with proper autoresizing handling will save time in the future.  This comment assumes that your designer is not expecting you to create different designs for iPhone 5 vs. 4.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to load the correct XIB at runtime. This means checking if `[[[UIScreen main screen] bounds] height]` returns 568. If so, load the XIB that is based on a 4"-screen, otherwise load the normal one. This all is done in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: Ok, sounds good.
Can you share some code how to load the XIB?